# Blurring the background

Tags: html, css, blur

My extra credit assignment is to create a page of menu items. When a menu image is clicked, it should blur the background, center the image, and display text about the menu item.

I have searched high and low for an answer, and I am completely lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am working with CSS, but if I need for it to do something on a click, then I would assume it would also require the use of JavaScript.

Comment: Try searching "blur background with CSS" on your search engine of choice or  even [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=blur+background+with+css).

**EDIT:** your question doesn't include the programming language you're working with. I assumed web, but your question as-is is objectively unanswerable.

Comment: I can only find how to blur a background image not the entire page.

Comment: Since you're new to SO, I highly recommend looking over [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The first Google result from my last comment contains the answer to your question. The more effort you put in, the more others will be motivated to help you.

Comment: I can blur the background, but I am probably simply too new to webpage design to understand how to make it happen when clicked, much less how to manipulate the image afterward. Thanks, anyway.